# Difference between h:link and h:outputLink

Tags: jsf-2

I have looked at the API's for both components but am not too sure why you would use one over the other?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputLink.html

Could somebody provide an example of why you would choose one over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

- `<h:link>` uses its `value` attribute as the link text and its `outcome` attribute to generate the linked-to URL via JSF navigation rules. This makes it useful for application-internal links. Also, this component was introduced only on JSF 2.0
- `<h:outputLink>` uses the `value` attribute directly as linked-to URL and the *content* of the tag as link text. This means the component cannot be used with navigation rules, but it can be used for direct and external links. It has been around since JSF 1.1.