# How can I get link for REST resource in JSF2

Tags: rest, jsf

Say, I have a simple REST service, that get content of PDF file:

```
@Path("/pdf")
@Stateless
public class GroupSheetEJB {

. . .
  @GET
  @Path("examsheet/{groupId: \\d+}/{course: \\d+}/{semester: \\d+}/{subjectId: \\d+}")
  @Produces("application/pdf")
  public Response examSheet(@PathParam("groupId") int groupCode, @PathParam("course") int course,
    @PathParam("semester") int semester, @PathParam("subjectId") int subjectCode) {
    try {
      StudyGroup grp = groups.get(groupCode);
      Subject sub = subjects.get(subjectCode);
      ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(getExamSheet(grp, sub, course, semester));
      return response.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new NotFoundException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Is any way to easily get link for this REST service from `<h:link>` component?
Now I use plain HTML  tag:

```
<a target="examsheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/webresources/#{semesterSubjectMarksMB.examSheetLink}">REST link</a>
```

`outcome` parameter of  with value `/webresources/#{semesterSubjectMarksMB.examSheetLink}` gets a disabled link.

Best regards.

Comment: If the `a` tag is enough for you why use `h:link`?

Comment: Enough, but <h:link> I can re-render by various conditions. I just want to know - maybe there are some mechanisms to get paths for REST services. Is the hardcoded links good solution?

Comment: You can wrap the `a` tag in `ui:fragment` pieces in order to decide it to render or not. If you want to use a JSF specific tag, use a `h:outputLink` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469298/difference-between-hlink-and-houtputlink