# Spring security logout link error:"This link is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched."

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I have a very simple logout link

```
<h:link value="Logout" outcome="#{request.contextPath}/logout" styleClass="nav-link" />
```

It gives me error `This link is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched.`

But if I use a form to logout like below, it works:

```
<h:form onsubmit="this.action='#{request.contextPath}/logout';">
    <p:commandButton value="Logout" ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

This is how I config security for logout:

```
http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").invalidateHttpSession(true);
```

May I know where is the problem?

**UPDATE**

Even if I hard code the full path, the error still there.

I have a link `contextPath/login`, which point to `login.xhtml`, if I remove the `login.xhtml` from my project directory, it will come out the same error message. Therefore I suspect the problem is because JSF could not find any file named `logout` in my project directory. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE 2**

I found that if I use `h:outputLink` then the problem will be solved, but instead of force to use `h:outputLink`, I want to know the actual cause of the problem. Is it because `h:link` is bound to the JSF navigation rule? Is there a way to solve this problem? or I have to use alternative, like `h:outputlink`?

Comment: Create a real simple plain had webapp without any spring in it. Does it work then? Read about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683584/what-url-to-use-to-link-navigate-to-other-jsf-pages. The outcome should never contain the context path... Wrong assumption and maybe even a wrong tutorial you used.

Comment: @Kukeltje I have updated my question.

Comment: read my comment

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry I am not really understand "Create a real simple plain had webapp without any spring in it", could you please explain a bit? sorry for my bad English

Comment: So you stopped reading after that? There was more: _"The outcome should never contain the context path"_

Comment: @Kukeltje the outcome is correct, which is `myProject/logout`, and if I copy paste the link run it, I can logout.

Comment: No the outcome should be just logout it is NOT a url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469298/difference-between-hlink-and-houtputlink